# MIPS - How do I branch and link if $a0 is greater than or equal to 1?

Tags: assembly, mips

My program has a recursive funciton that takes an integer as input and prints n, n-1...1, 0, 0, 1 ...n

Here is the recursive function:

```
RDemo:
    
    addi $sp, $sp -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    
    #print $a0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    
    addi $a0, $a0, -1
    bgezal $a0, RDemo
    addi $a0, $a0, 1
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
```

the problem is that I need it to stop at 1, not 0.

For example, with an input of 3 it should output ( 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3) instead of (3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3)

I am using the bgezal instruction ( branch if greater than or equal to 0 and link) because it is closest to what I need ( I need branch if grater than or equal to 1 and link).

As far as I can tell, there are only two MIPS branch and link instructions. begzal and bltzal (branch if less than 0 and link)

Is there a way I can accomplish what I want to without creating any other subroutines?

Comment: You can always use a normal `blez` over an unconditional `bal` (relative) or `jal` (section-absolute).  Or offset your counter by one (into another register) in order to get something to branch on, or `slt` to generate a branch condition.  Or in this case optimize your code into 2 loops instead of recursion, using no stack space instead of O(n) space.

Comment: BTW, your "recursion" is using a custom calling convention where the call "returns" `n-1` in `$a0`.  vs. the standard MIPS calling convention where return values are in `$v0`, and `$a` registers are call-clobbered.   https://godbolt.org/z/hrx4rdqaM shows how GCC uses stack space to save the incoming arg across a call if you don't write it with a return value.

Comment: Also, if you can't do something in one instruction, then use more than one!

Comment: bgezal / bltzal only check the sign bit.  `slt` don't work, 0 and 1 are both non-negative, so it's not directly usable with conditional b-and-link.  Maybe just `addiu $t0, $a0, -1` to get a number one lower into a register, for `bggezal $t0, RDemo`.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you, yes I ran into that issue.  The I did exactly what u said and and its working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a normal `blez` over an unconditional `bal` (relative) or `jal` (section-absolute). Or offset your counter by one (into another register) in order to get something to branch on. Or in this case optimize your code into 2 loops instead of recursion, using no stack space instead of O(n) space.

Unfortunately `slt` doesn't work directly with `bgezal` / `bltzal`.  The both only check the sign bit, but `slt` generates a 0 or 1, both of which are non-negative.

```
RDemo:
    addi $sp, $sp -4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    
    #print $a0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    addi $t0, $a0, -2       # tmp = n-2
    addi $a0, $a0, -1       # n--
    bgezal $t0, RDemo       # if (n-1 >= 0) RDemo(n);
         # returns with $a0 unchanged, custom calling convention
    addi $a0, $a0, 1
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
    
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    jr $ra
```

`tmp = n-2` on the original `n`, instead of `tmp = new_n - 1`, has better instruction-level parallelism.  A CPU able to run multiple instructions per cycle could run those both in parallel, since there's no RAW dependency between them.

In this case, **where integer overflow is probably not a concern for `n-1`**, we can get away with just one extra instruction vs. your original code and still use a conditional-b-and-link, instead of branching around an unconditional call.  If `a0 = INT_MIN` was a possibility, `a0-1 >= 0` would be different from `a0 >= 1`.  Since we used `addi` instead of the normal `addiu`, this will actually trap on signed-overflow and only print `-2147483647` twice if called with that arg, not print 2^31 times (or actually stop on stack overflow from recursion.)

---

BTW, your "recursion" is using a custom calling convention where the call "returns" `n` in `$a0` vs. the standard MIPS calling convention where return values are in `$v0`, and `$a` arg-passing registers are call-clobbered. https://godbolt.org/z/hrx4rdqaM shows how GCC uses stack space to save the incoming arg across a call if you don't write it with a return value.

This is kind of half way in between iterative and recursive, keeping registers across a call.  But you can describe it to a C compiler with `a0 = RDemo(a0)` since there's only one arg.

---

#### MIPS32r6

If you were programming for **MIPS32r6** ([MIPS manual from dec 2016](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/downloads-mips/documents/MD00086-2B-MIPS32BIS-AFP-6.06.pdf)), `BGTZALC rt, offset` would be available, a full set of branch-and-link with any of the usual comparison predicates.  The "C" is for "compact" - no branch delay slot.

Real MIPS does have a branch delay slot, but your code looks like it's for a simplified MIPS without one, otherwise the `addi $a0, $a0, 1` would run before the callee.  And MIPS32r6 removed the old `bgezal` except for the `bgezal $zero` case, unconditional `bal`.

MARS may simulate MIPS32, but not MIPS32r6 which reorganized some opcodes.  (MIPS32r6 is of limited interest these days except for the architecture design choices; the company developing that owns the ISA has switched over to RISC-V.)